# Remove recently added item from List

Tags: c#, list

```
List <Customer> collCustList = new List<Customer>();
```

I tried

```
if(A==B)
        collCustList.Add(new Customer(99, "H", "P"));

else
        collCustList.Remove(new Customer(99, "H", "P"));
```

but it doesn't work

How could I remove the `new item(new Customer(99, "H", "P"))` I just added?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to work, you can use `List<T>` and have `Customer` implement `IEquatable<Customer>`.  Simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Customer : IEquatable<Customer>
{
    public int i;
    public string c1, c2;
    public Customer(int i, string c1, string c2)
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    bool System.IEquatable<Customer>.Equals(Customer o)
    {
        if(o == null)
            return false;
        return this.i == o.i &&
            this.c1 == o.c1 &&
            this.c2 == o.c2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object o)
    {
        return o != null && 
            this.GetType() == o.GetType() &&
            this.Equals((Customer) o);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return i.GetHashCode() ^
            c1.GetHashCode() ^
            c2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of removing the Customer instance you just added, you're trying to remove a new Customer instance. You'll need to get a reference to the first Customer instance and remove that, eg:

```
Customer customer = new Customer(99, "H", "P");
collCustList.Add(customer);
collCustList.Remove(customer);
```

or, more succinctly, if you're know you're removing the most recent customer you may do:

```
collCustList.Remove(collCustList.Last());
```

If you don't have an existing reference to the Customer instance you're trying to remove, you could use a Linq query like so:

```
Customer customer = collCustList.Where(c => c.Number == 99 && c.Type == "H" /* etc */).FirstOrDefault();
if (customer != null)
{
    collCustList.Remove(customer);
}
```

or even just use the RemoveAll() method:

```
collCustList.RemoveAll(c => c.Number == 99 && c.Type == "H" /* etc */);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam.

I have trouble building Customer customer = collCustList.Select(c => c.Number == 99 && c.Type == "H" /* etc */).FirstOrDefault(); 


what I miss? Thanks

Comment: Sorry - I don't know what your customer properties are based on the code posted, so I used examples. The 'c.xxx' properties should be replaced with whatever your Customer class property names are.

Comment: Thanks, I did replace the properties. 
the build error is
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to Customer

Comment: Arrgh - I keep getting these mixed up! Try collCustList.Where() instead :). (updated post)

Answer (score 2):

new Customer() will create a new instance which is different from the one which you are adding into the List. So List will not be able to match an object for removal.

So use the way which Robert suggested or you have to iterate through the List for matching data(99, "H", "P") and then remove using matched customer object's reference.

/jay

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer c = new Customer(99, "H", "P");
List collCustList = new List(); collCustList.Add(c);
collCustList.Remove(c);
```

This works because it is removing the same object that was added.  Your code is trying to remove another new object that is not the same as the object you just added (it is a different object).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the remove is not right after add. I can not keep the customer c. Sorry I didn't make it clear in my original post

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Remove()`, then `Customer` class would need to implement [EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If u want to removeat

```
  private void removeButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
        if ( displayListBox.SelectedIndex != -1 )
          displayListBox.Items.RemoveAt( displayListBox.SelectedIndex );
      }
```